# Intermittent Non-Functioning JavaFX Buttons

Tags: javafx

I recently released a new version of a JavaFX app that I designed, and I've had a report of an odd issue that has me completely stumped.  I'm hoping someone here will have seen something similar in the past and/or have a suggestion as to what might be causing it.

I wrote a desktop app for stamp collectors. When the user loads a scan of a bunch of postage stamps, the app extracts the individual stamps from the scan, rotates and crops them, and saves them to file.  The main interface looks like this.

[App Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apbwS.jpg)

The app is written in Java (21) with JavaFX (21) for the UI, using OpenCV (4.9.0) to handle the image manipulation and a couple other libraries to handle metadata read/write.  Other than one block of code handling the loading of the OpenCV libraries, the code is the same across all operating systems.  The artifacts are bundled into an installer with JRE and all additional supporting files using install4j, so all the user has to do is download the single-file installer and the app will install and run with no additional requirements on the end-user's part.

I currently have it running on MacOS (Intel only), Windows 10 & 11 (64-bit only), and Ubuntu on my test machines, and it's working great.  No major issues.  I have received reports from dozens of other users on all those platforms that it's working great, no issues.  But...

I received a report from two users – one on Windows 10 and one on Windows 11 – that the buttons in the toolbar are non-functional.  The app opens fine.  The controls and buttons in the left sidebar work.  The app will process images dropped onto it using drag-and-drop, rotating and cropping them and saving them to file.  But the buttons in the toolbar don't do anything.  When the user clicks any of the toolbar buttons, the button is highlighted indicating it has received the focus, but nothing happens.

The code for the buttons in the toolbars is setup in the same manner as the other controls that are working.  The only difference is that they're in the toolbar.  Each contains a call to a method elsewhere in the code that performs some function.  There isn't any commonality between the non-functioning buttons other than their location.  Two open file choosers to load/save a file, three are for loading/saving/resetting defaults values for the controls, two open new stages with subfunctions on them, and the rest are toggles that enable/disable certain functions within the app.

The rest of the code in the app works fine for those two users, so it's not a case of something blocking the execution of the app wholesale.  And, of course, it's working perfectly for dozens of others including me on all my test machines.

I've connected with one of the users via Microsoft Teams to watch him try to use the app, and his reports are accurate, so it's not a case of user error.

I created a version with error logging enabled, to write any errors to a text file on the user's desktop.  When one of the users with the problem tried to run this version, it generated the error log, but the only entry was this error saying it couldn't create the lock file for the error log, so the error logging went no further.

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\[username omitted]\Desktop\error.log.lck
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:119)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:309)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:369)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:512)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:308)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newMethodAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newMethodAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.acquireMethodAccessor(Method.java:726)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

This is also bizarre, because the logging works correctly on all my machines, so I'm guessing it may be a related issue.  Considering the nature of this error, I thought it might be a permissions issue or an anti-virus or security setting blocking certain functions or access to the file system, so I had the user try running it as Administrator with his anti-virus disabled, but no luck.

So at this point, I'm out of ideas.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?  What could be causing buttons in the toolbar to be non-functional, while the rest of the app works fine?  And only on certain machines – one Win10 and one Win11 – when it works fine on other computers with those OS's?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Are there other users on Windows 10 and Windows 11 that are **not** experiencing problems? Also, are you saying that none of the toolbar buttons are working?

Comment: Yes.  I have test systems running Win10 and Win11 that it works fine on, and I have received reports from about two dozen other Windows users that it's working for them with no issues.  It's just these two users.  That's what makes me think it's something unique to their systems.

And none of the toolbar buttons are working for those two users.  All buttons in the app that aren't on the toolbar work correctly, but none of those on the toolbar do.

Comment: This type of behavior is often due to not handling threads correctly. Do you have threads in your app?

Comment: I do have several threads in the app, mostly related to the use of a progress bar at several points in the processing of images.  Can you elaborate on how thread handling might cause this, and why it might only affect a couple users?

Comment: How much can you isolate the problem? Does a very simple application with a single `Button` in a `ToolBar` work? Does the problem only occur with install4j-packaged applications?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't take a lot of the normal troubleshooting steps because it works great on all my systems (three Macs, two Windows 10, two Windows 11, and one Ubuntu).  I have to rely on one of the two users who is having the problem to test out any troubleshooting steps.  I'll see if I can send him a basic app that's not packaged and walk him through running it.

Comment: @PostmasterGS *"Can you elaborate on how thread handling might cause this, and why it might only affect a couple users?"* -> See [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  If you corrupt the application state by reading or writing the scene graph off the JavaFX thread, you will encounter race conditions which can be unpredictable in their occurrence and outcome.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm familiar with that issue, as I had to tackle it at a couple points in developing the app.  I'll double check it, but I'm not confident that's the issue here.  The buttons are non-functional on initial load, and any off-thread actions are much further down the line sequentially, deep in the image processing code.

Comment: Does this *always* happen on the specific machines, or is it intermittent on those machines?

Comment: I've had two reports of this issue.  One user hasn't responded to emails.  The other has been working with me to troubleshoot, and it happens 100% of the time on his machine.  Uninstall, reinstall, reboot, anti-virus on/off, nothing seems to affect it.  The behavior is almost like there's a security setting that's limiting the app's access to the file system and it's ability to run certain code, but it seems random.  Images can be written to his desktop, but the log's lock file can't.  Can run code to load/process images via drag/drop, but not any code that's triggered by a toolbar button.

Comment: Might you be losing a [`WeakListener`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/beans/WeakListener.html) on one execution path that is restored on another execution path?